# How do I clear ModelMap session?

Tags: java, session, spring-boot

I have this annotation at the top of my controller:

```
@SessionAttributes("user")
```

And this mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logout(ModelMap model){
    model.clear();
```

But when I navigate to that URL it's still able to retrieve the User session attributes..
How do I properly clear the ModelMap value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I need this signature instead w/ SessionStatus:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logout(SessionStatus status){
    status.setComplete();
    return "redirect:/";
}
```